# How to retrieve json data from a post request url using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, post, webhooks

First, I'm sorry if any of my word confused you guys.

I created a webhook url from a third party platform(Webhook.site). This site gave me an url to receive request (GET,POST,etc..). When request is sent to this url, I will see a json type result like this: {
"employees":["John", "Anna", "Peter"]
}

But that just the UI, how can I retrieve the result using VB.net?
Do I need to install a new package for this?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: What I see on the platform just like this, I dont know how to get the data from that webhook url(or is it possible or not):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXEVA.png)

Comment: This is quite a broad topic.  Generally, you would want to Deserialise that response json into a collection of a type.  You can use the Paste Special -> Paste Json as Class option in Visual studio to give you a class structure for that type, heaps of examples of how around the internet.  Once you've got your collection you can display that in the UI the same way you would any other data collection object

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at the documentation for `HttpClient`.  You don't need a new package.